# Pause/Resume Flink job during migrations

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using `Apache Flink` to propagate updates from a given set of `Kafka` topics into an `Elasticsearch` cluster.

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the `Elasticsearch` cluster evolves and I have to **(1)** modify the mappings, **(2)** copy over the data...and by the time I have to point the `Flink` jobs to the new alias/index, there are plenty of updates that made it to the old index.

So I wonder what's the best way to approach this. I can have downtime, but I would like to avoid this if possible. I was trying to make the `Flink` jobs to slowdown or pause the (`Kafka`) input sources until the migration finishes, but I didn't find any endpoint for this.

> The `Flink` jobs run in **application** mode.

If anyone can shed some light on how to accomplish this: pause/resume the jobs via an API or something similar, I will really appreciate the input. The only constraint I have is around stopping the applications (as in stopping/killing pods): it's possible, but too troublesome due to access constraints to the `Kubernetes` clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably look into stopping the job with a save point using Flink REST API: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-stop

If that Flink app is pretty big and has lots of state, you can also try to just stop sending data to the input Kafka topic if you don't want to stop it (assuming that it can properly write with the new mappings and indeces after you've made the required ES cluster changes without any change in the Flink Job). It is a bit of overhead, but you could have different topics for your producers and Flink sources, and have another simple Flink job mirror data from one topic (where producers produce to) to the other (where Flink consumes from). When you want to stop writing to ES, just stop that job using the REST API. To not write a new Flink job you could use MirrorMaker or similar, but to stop it you may have to kill its pod.

Or another option is architecting the Elasticsearch indexes so they can support your cluster evolution without having to stop the Flink app. It is hard to know what do you'd need to exactly change, but by writing into aliases and playing with the write index flag you may be able to achieve what you want. I've done this in the past, but it is true that if your mappings change a lot it may be hard to do,